# Problem with the first layers on the print

Tags: print-quality

I ran out of ideas on what could cause my problem.

- Ender 3 Pro
- Nozzle temp 200 °C
- Bed temp 60 °C
- PLA filament

Please look at the pictures. The first layers don't look nice. The top and the sides are perfect.
This happens in every print. With and without raft or brim. The strange thing is that raft and brim looks very good on the bedside. Is there some settings I am missing out on here?
Tried with Creality Slicer that came with the printer, and the Ultimaker Cura slicer.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The filament is not flattened, it looks like the nozzle deposits round filament strings while in fact they should be flattened more. This usually indicates that the nozzle to bed distance is too large. A perfect distance is obtained with plain A4 or US letter paper (usually 0.1 mm thick; or 0.004") during levelling where there is a slight drag/friction force observed when the paper is pulled between bed and nozzle. Alternatively, you can use feeler gauges:

[image]

Considering that the raft is printer well, it could well be that the initial nozzle to bed distance is correct, but the distance between the raft and the first layer of the product is too large.